# SQL search query based on separate words

Tags: sql, search

I currently have a SQL stored procedure that is set up that is based on receiving a parameter search string, (for example 'Netgear WiFI Switch') the stored procedure then does a wildcard LIKE search on this .i.e.

```
WHERE COL1 LIKE '%Netgear WiFi Switch'%
```

This works fine however I want to elaborate on this by searching on any of the words. For example the example query would miss out products that say 'Netgear Switch WiFi' because of the different order.

So I need to split the words and do a wildcard search on each word. (%Netgear% AND %Switch% AND %WiFi%)

So my question is how would I begin to look at splitting the string into the necessary words, apply these to variables and then do a dynamic WHERE based on how many variables have been created from the splitting of the search string.

Thank you

Comment: You should specify your SQL platform as this is likely to be platform specific

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use sql server FULLTEXT Search  it will be very easy and efficient .If you don't like to enable fulltext search  Use the following  query it will give you basic idea how to approach

```
DECLARE @keyword varchar(100)='Project'
-- remove double spaces
 while CHARINDEX('  ',@keyword) > 1            
  begin            
     SET @keyword=REPLACE(@keyword,'  ',' ')            
  end   
SET @keyword=REPLACE(@keyword,' ','%'' AND COL1 LIKE ''%')+'%'''
DECLARE @str varchar(max)=''
SET @str='SELECT  COL1 FROM dbo.table 
WHERE COL1 Like ''%'+ @keyword

EXEC (@str)
```

You can use execute_sql  instead of exec

Comment: Brilliant answer, both the fulltext option and also the code worked fine

Answer (score 0):

I would create a t-sql function that takes that phrase (set of words) and splits it by a space and then searches that column text value based on your algorithm.  This way you can still embed your logic in a where clause..it is abstracted, so that function is re-usable in other areas of your code.

This may work for simple search.  Searching for multiple words might be harder and you would need a hard-coded lookup.  Indexes are not going to work since functions are evaluated at every row iteration.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend you to use Lucene or Solr for search. They are a lot more efficient than using SQL queries in handling these words combinations by making use of text indexes. If you still want to search for text in SQLs, the better solution would be to use Boolean search:

[Boolean Full-Text Searches](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//fulltext-boolean.html)

You can split your string into a number of word tokens. Then, you can eliminate all the common words ( only 2 characters or less or very common words like "for", "with" , etc). After that you can use the + or - operators for your query. Another optimization would be to stored the commonly searched phrases. But it is probably out of scope of your question. Hope it helps :)